# How do I install GraphViz in Spyder 3.6

Tags: python, spyder

I have seen a Stack Overflow repository and there it was mentioned that first 'pip install GraphViz' and then 'pip install pydotplus'.Now I have successfully installed both in my C:\Users\ChirantanGupta\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.6.0.0\python-3.6.0b3.amd64\Lib\site-packages. Both exist over there but whenever I try to run this code , it shows an error: 
The error is:

File "C:\Users\ChirantanGupta\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.6.0.0\python-3.6.0b3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pydotplus\graphviz.py", line 1918, in write
    fobj.write(self.create(prog, format))

File "C:\Users\ChirantanGupta\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.6.0.0\python-3.6.0b3.amd64\lib\site-packages\pydotplus\graphviz.py", line 1960, in create
    'GraphViz\'s executables not found')

InvocationException: GraphViz's executables not found

Here is the code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree
iris = load_iris()
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
with open("iris.dot", 'w') as f:
    f = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=f)
import os
os.unlink('iris.dot')

import pydotplus 
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None) 
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data) 
graph.write_pdf("iris.pdf") 

from IPython.display import Image  
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=None,feature_names=iris.feature_names,  
                         class_names=iris.target_names,  
                         filled=True, rounded=True,  
                         special_characters=True)
graph = pydotplus.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data)  
Image(graph.create_png())
```

Comment: You also need to install graphviz itself. http://www.graphviz.org/Download.php You've installed a python library that lets you invoke GraphViz from python but not the actual GraphViz executables.

Comment: I have already installed graphviz as graphviz-2.38.zip and extracted it on the PATH:C:\Users\ChirantanGupta\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.6.0.0\python-3.6.0b3.amd64\Lib\site-packages. Yet my code is giving the same error as before.I am trying this simple thing for the last 2 days. Please help.

Comment: Did you install pygraphviz? I see that you installed Graphviz by using pip install Graphviz, but did you do pip install pygraphviz?

Comment: No I didn't as there was no mention of this anywhere.

Comment: Not sure if it will work but it is worth a shot

Comment: You need to put it in your PATH not in the site packages dir.

Comment: Alternatively, install GraphViz with the provided msi installer, don't use the zip.

Comment: Nope still not working.Saying ModuleNotFoundError:'No module named setup_commands'

Comment: That's a different error though. What is saying that? What is the full and exact error? Update your question with the new info and whatever else you have done.

Answer (score 2):

To install Graphviz in WinPython:

1. Ensure the Graphviz executables are installed. If not, go to the [Graphviz download page](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/download/), download the Windows binaries and install it to a desired location. As an example, let's assume that after installation the Graphviz root directory is `c:\tools\graphviz`.
2. Ensure the Graphviz `bin` subfolder is added to your `PATH` environment variable. Following the example, open a Command Prompt window and type:

   ```
   setx PATH=%PATH%;c:\tools\graphviz\bin;
   ```
3. Install the `graphviz` package in WinPython, either using `pip` or using the WinPython Package Manager (see [here](https://github.com/winpython/winpython/wiki/Installing-Additional-Packages) for more details).
4. Test that all is working properly by running the Graphviz [hello.py](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html) example.

Comment: This works for me. To add Graphviz to the `PATH` I used: `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\tools\graphviz\bin"`

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this:

- find the "python._pth" file next to "\WinPython-64bit-3.6.0‌​.0\python-3.6.0b3.am‌​d64\python.exe"
- rename it as "zpython._pth"